# How to remove the # character from this script?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a script to preform an ajax call from page to page
the thing that i can't understand is why with each href click 
the browser current location changes to www.blabla/#index
take a look at the code below, my target is to change the current location 
to something with out "#" -www.blabla/index

```
$("document").ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#tabs-bar li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#tabs-bar li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    /// $('#content').fadeOut('100');
    $('#content').empty();
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#profile-cv').addClass("loading");
    //$('#content').append('<div class="loading"></div>');

    setTimeout(function () { loadContent(); }, 1000);

    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#profile-cv').load(toLoad,showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#profile-cv').append(hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#profile-cv').removeClass("loading");

    }
    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: i meant name of the target page + #, index click = #index contact = #contact

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the default action of the event from executing.

Use `e.preventDefault();` to achieve this - `e` is the first argument of your callback function:

```
$('#tabs-bar li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content';
    ...
});
```

Comment: i think i mis explained my self, i want the same effect without the # thats all

Answer (score 0):

You are setting

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
```

The location.hash **always** adds the "#".

Look at the [PJAX library](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), so you can modify the url.

**Update**

The library uses the new HTML5 `history.pushState` API. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in any IE, except the IE 10.

[This nice tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) should help you to implement it.

If you need fallback solutions for old browsers, you can use libraries like [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js).

Comment: any other solutions you might know? i prefer to use the current jquery script

Comment: I updated my answer. Please mark it as solved if it answers your question

Comment: is it possible to simply take location.pathname and manipulate it?      for example location.pathname returns = blabla/tmp/index.html and use substr to remove the last five char? ".html"

Comment: `location.pathname` returns informations about your URL, but you can't set/manipulate it. As i said, you can use `location.hash` and accept the `#` or you use `history.pushState`.